# Доступ к ресурсам в сборке, загруженной через Assembly.Load

Tags: c#, resources, assembly

Есть библиотека, в которой реализован метод с подобным кодом:

```
var rm = new ResourceManager("Reports.Resources.lang", typeof(Reports).Assembly);
var dep = rm.GetString("Department", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
```

Соответственно, в проекте есть ресурсный файл `lang.ru-RU.resx`, который компилируется в `Reports.resources.dll` (которую я еще как ссылку добавил, точно не знаю, надо ли так делать).

Если подключать библиотеку напрямую, то при вызове метода все работает нормально, забирается нужный ресурсный файл (их несколько), можно получить доступ к нужной строке.

Но если подключать библиотеку программно через `Assembly.Load()`, создавать объект класса и вызывать тот же самый метод, то ресурсный файл не находится.

Вопрос, что делать? Как заставить во втором случае правильно считать ресурс?

Comment: А в каком каталоге лежит библиотека по отношению к основной программе? И в каком каталоге файл с ресурсами. Это важно.

Comment: Библиотека лежит в подкаталоге (допустим Data), а ресурсные файлы в Data/ru-Ru, Data/en-US.

Comment: Ага, вот в этом проблема. Перекиньте в основной каталог, должно взлететь. Или нужно заменить `Assembly.Load` на что-то другое, сейчас гляну точно.

Comment: Закинуть ресурные файлы в корень папки с библиотеки или в папку с основной проблемой?

Comment: Ресурсы должны быть по идее в `.\ru-RU\Reports.resources.dll` и т. д.

Comment: Согласно [этой статье](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/05/29/choosing-a-binding-context/), вам может помочь `LoadFrom` вместо `Load`. Но попробуйте сначала решение с перемещением из каталога `Data` наружу.

Comment: Данное решение помогло. Но как все же сделать, чтобы ресурные файлы искали в подкаталоге? Это все же важно(
Библиотека подгружается через LoadFile

Comment: `LoadFile` или `Load`? Это _совсем_ не одно и то же. Для чего вам понадобился опасный `LoadFile`?

Comment: Окей, раз помогло, то напишу как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы грузите вашу сборку через `Assembly.Load`, зависимости ищутся в том же месте, что и для основного приложения, то есть в каталоге приложения и его подкаталогах вида `en-US`, `ru-RU` (для языковых ресурсов). Расследование в комментариях показало, что ваши файлы лежат в подкаталоге `Data`, поэтому локализованные ресурсы и не находятся.

Самое простое решение — перенесите библиотеку в каталог с основной программой, а её локализации — а подкаталоги `en-US`, `ru-RU` и т. д. каталога программы.

Другой путь — изменить конфигурацию программы, позволив ей находить зависимости в других каталогах. [MSDN говорит](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx), что нужно внести секцию в `app.config`:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <!-- здесь должен быть указан ваш каталог Data -->
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Более строгий путь, с указанием `publicKeyToken`, описан [здесь](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/837908) (такой путь предотвратит загрузку *чего угодно*, а разрешит лишь загрузку нужной сборки):

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Reports" culture="neutral"
                publicKeyToken="<здесь укажите токен>"/>
            <codeBase version="тут версия" href="FILE://тут путь"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Вам придётся подписать сборку (а также зависимые локализованные сборки!) при помощи `sn -k`.

Ещё один путь, описанный там же — подписаться на событие `AssemblyResolve`, и грузить сборку через `LoadFrom` в нём.

---

Впрочем, согласно [этой статье](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/05/29/choosing-a-binding-context/), вам может помочь `LoadFrom` вместо `Load`. Но это не вполне чистое решение, если загружаемая библиотека имеет зависимости от библиотек основного приложения.

Comment: За описание секции в конфиг файле большое спасибо, как раз это и помогло. 
P.S. Я не мог загружать по другому, т.к мне нужно было именно позволить загружать произвольные библиотеки (правда я забирал оттуда только определенные классы)

Comment: @craimez: Вот и отлично, хорошо, что помогло.